# Using a header file to define mt19937 and normal_distribution

Tags: c++, random, header-files, gaussian, normal-distribution

I am using the following routine to generate random numbers chosen from a Gaussian/Normal distribution:

When everything is in a single file to compile it's rather straightforward:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double m;
    double v;
  int seed=100; 
    int samplesize=10;
    double ls [samplesize]; //to store as a list

    m = 0.0;
    v = 0.05;
    mt19937 e2(seed);

    normal_distribution<float> dist(m, sqrt(v));

  for (int i=0; i<samplesize; i++){
        ls[i] = dist(e2);
        cout << ls[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now I am trying to do something similar but I'd like to be able to define `e2` and the `dist` globally, or simply first in a hearder file `.h` and then call them in various `.C` files of my program.
My attempts keep running into `error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘std::mt19937 e2(int)’` kind of errors.

The aim is to:

- Define `e2` and `dist` in a header file.
- Seed the `e2` in a `.C` file that loads a file of parameters containing where the seed is given.
- Use `dist(e2)` in my `.C` files whereever I have to generate such number.

My attempt:

In the header file I have written:

```
#include <random>

std::mt19937 e2(int sd); //sd for seed to be read from file later.
std::normal_distribution<float> dist(double meanNormal, double varNormal); //define generally, mean and var to be read from file.
```

Then in my `setup.C` file where I read the parameters I try to generate an instance of `e2` and `dist`:

```
e2(seed); //seed read from file before.
dist(mean,sqrt(var)); //mean and var are double variables defined in this file.
```

Now in my main program file, when I try to generate a number from `dist` using `dist(e2)` I get a non-static member function error as shown above.
Any help in how to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in the first example you declare a variable `e2` and `dist` and in the second you define functions.

What you want is this header:

```
#include <random>

std::mt19937 e2;
std::normal_distribution<float> dist;
```

In your main or `.C` file you should:

```
e2 = std::mt19937(seed);
dist = normal_distribution<float>(m, sqrt(v));
```

Also you should include a header guard to prevent multiple declarations. I assume you already have one but didn't include it for brevity.

Comment: This fixed it brilliantly!

Answer (score 2):

You created header with declaration of 2 functions

```
std::mt19937 e2(int sd);
std::normal_distribution<float> dist(double meanNormal, double varNormal);
```

function `f2` takes one argument and returns `std::mt19937` object, function `dist` takes two arguments and returns `std::normal_distribution` object.
In your main file you called these functions by

```
e2(seed); //seed read from file before.
dist(mean,sqrt(var)); //mean and var are double variables defined in this file.
```

and you got compiler error in this line

```
ls[i] = dist(e2); // <----
```

because you want to call `dist` function with `e2` function as parameter, it is not possible. `dist` function expects two double arguments.

If you want to treat `dist` and `e2` as global variables to generate random values in multiple sources file you can declare in header function like this

```
double myrandom ();
```

and define it as

```
double myrandom ()
{
  static mt19937 e2(100);
  static normal_distribution<float> dist(0.0, sqrt(0.05));
  // e2 and dist will be created during first call of this function
  return dist(e2);
}
```

Comment: In the single file example I have provided there are no errors. The error occurs only when I try to split things up using header files and multiple `.C` files.

Comment: after splitting code into header and main files, you got error in this line `ls[i] = dist(e2); ` becase in header you declared e2 and dist as functions. I agree `ls[i] = dist(e2)` in one main file works.

Comment: Oh I see. So I shouldn't define it in the header file altogether right? I mean I can do something similar to your `double myrandom` in the main file itself?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. `std::mt19937 e2(int sd);`

Not really sure why you think that would work... as pointed out this declares a function.

What you can do is to put

```
std::mt19937 e2;
```

in your header file and then from your .cpp file call

```
e2.seed(something);
```

This however seems like a good chance to make a small class to encapsulate this for you.

```
class RNG_class {
private:
    std::mt19937 e2;
    std::normal_distribution<float> dist;
public:
    RNG_class(int seed, double meanNormal, double varNormal) : e2(seed), dist(meanNormal, varNormal) {}
    float get() {
        return dist(e2);
    }
};
```

From your `.cpp` you can then do

```
RNG_class rng(100, m, sqrt(v));
...
ls[i] = rng.get();
```